How do I get property of custom entity like how its done in EFCore OnModelCreating
Entity class
public class MyEntity {
    public List<MyProperty> Properties;
    public Type EntityType;
}

Property class
public class MyProperty {
    public string PropertyName;
    public Type PropertyType;
}

I have an entity builder class which have a method creating new property builder, passing existing MyProperty instance to it.
It gets called like this: .Property(Blog x => x.Post)
public class MyEntityBuilder<TEntity> {
    private MyEntity entity;
    public MyPropertyBuilder<TProperty> Property<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertyExpression) {
        MyProperty property = **Do something with the propertyExpression**
        return new MyPropertyBuilder(property);
    }
}

I`ve tried to look into EFCore internals, but did not understand a lot. Basically, I want to compile my expression into  something like:
MyProperty property = entity.Properties
    .Single(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(TProperty) && x.PropertyName == propertyExpression.GetPropertyName())

Im struggling with getting the name of entity`s property, which was passed in expression

Found an answer. Use GetPropertyAccess() method of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure namespace.
